# Getting an error when using CONCAT in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a query where I combine two columns and separate them with an **x** in between.

I'm also trying to get some other columns from the same table. However, I get the following error.

> Error: No matching signature for function CONCAT for argument types: FLOAT64, FLOAT64. Supported signatures: CONCAT(STRING, [STRING, ...]); CONCAT(BYTES, [BYTES, ...]).

Here is my code:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(right,'x',left),
  position,
  numbercreated,
  Madefrom
FROM
  table
WHERE
Date = "2018-10-07%"
```

I have tried also putting a cast before but that did not work.

`SELECT Concast(cast(right,'x',left)), position,...`

`SELECT Concast(cast(right,'x',left)as STRING), position,...`

Why am I getting this error? 
Are there any fixes? 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast each value *before* the `concat()`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(right as string), 'x', CAST(left as string)),
       position, numbercreated, Madefrom
FROM table
WHERE Date = '2018-10-07%';
```

If you want a particular format, then use the `FORMAT()` function.

I also doubt that your `WHERE` will match anything.  If `Date` is a string, then you probably want `LIKE`:

```
WHERE Date LIKE '2018-10-07%';
```

More likely, you should use the `DATE` function or direct comparison:

```
WHERE DATE(Date) = '2018-10-07'
```

or:

```
WHERE Date >= '2018-10-07' AND
      Date < '2018-10-08'
```

Comment: Thank you. Solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try like below by using `safe_cast`:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(SAFE_CAST( right as string ),'x',SAFE_CAST(left as string)),
    position,
    numbercreated,
    Madefrom
FROM
    table
WHERE
    Date = '2018-10-07'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to fix your issue with CONCAT is to use FROMAT function as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1.01 AS `right`, 2.0 AS `left`
)
SELECT FORMAT('%g%s%g', t.right, 'x', t.left)
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

result will be

```
Row f0_  
1   1.01x2
```

Note: in above specific example  - you could use even simpler statement

```
FORMAT('%gx%g', t.right, t.left)
```

You can see more for supporting [formats](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#format)

Few recommendations - try not to use keywords as a column names/aliases. If for some reason you do use - wrap such with backtick or prefix it with table name/alias

Yet another comment - looks like you switched your values positions  - your right one is on left side and left one is on right - might be exactly what you need but wanted to mention